# WSO2 - SP/IDP initiated authentication - SAML assertion

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

Using WSO2 5.1.0. Needs to send SAML assertion like firstName, lastName from WSO2 as IDP to SP. Refer [Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB3jK.png). User profile do have first name and last name values.

Restarted WSO2, no error in logs. But I don't receive these values in SAML response sent from WSO2 to my Service porvider.

Answer (score 0):

For this, in your Service Provider's SAML Configuration, you need to make sure following two checkboxes are selected.

Enable Attribute Profile
 Include Attributes in the Response Always

Then, inside the Claim Configuration section of the Service Provider configuration, you need to add the particular claims you need to receive as Requested Claims. Then these claims will be included in SAML response.

If you want the claims to have a different key name, you can define a custom claim dialect there and provide your own key names for claims.